# Convert string JSON to multidimensional JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a Json: `{"01-08":"1500","02-08":"2500","03-08":"500"}`

Now I would want something like:

```
[['01-08', 1500],['02-08', 2500],['03-08', 500]]
```

Thank you Advance

Comment: Check out the relevant utilities from underscore or lodash.

Answer (score 1):

This is very primitive answer, So I wont give you any description.

```
var obj = {
    "01-08": "1500",
    "02-08": "2500",
    "03-08": "500"
};

var array = [];

for (key in obj) {
    array.push([key, obj[key]]);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Worked fine...Thanks a lot